# Can't find .emacs file

Tags: 17.10, emacs

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 and installed Emacs25 from the Software Centre. I tried to add MELPA to the .emacs file, but running `emacs .emacs` created a new file. I have not been able to find the config file I am looking for under any other file name. How can I access this file?
Thanks.

UPDATE:

After making a customization within an emacs window, the .emacs file showed up and I was able to add MELPA to it. Not sure why this happened still though.

Comment: Do you see other `.filename` or hidden files?

Comment: Yes. I checked the files app and did C-h. There was a .emacs.d folder but nothing useful inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for the file to exist just because you installed emacs. The file contains user customization, so it didn't exist until you started the program and did some customization. Creating the file in an editor is perfectly fine.